# What are these variants (Nguyễn and Nguyến) of Vietnamese last name Nguyen?

Tags: translation, vietnamese

I saw these two variants (Nguyễn and Nguyến) of spelling of Nguyen. Which of the two variants are the most original and correct Vietnamese spelling of Nguyen? Are both legitimate representation of Vietnamese spelling of Nguyen?

Comment: Even without knowing any Vietnamese: A quick check with the [Vietnamese Wikipedia](https://vi.wikipedia.org) confirms Nguyễn as the spelling of the Vietnamese surname. There are a few stray (35 vs. ~25000) occurrences of the spelling Nguyến throughout the Wikipedia, but I am not sure if they represent different words or are just spelling errors.

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica At least some of them are definitely just spelling errors, such as the references to “_Nguyến tác_” at the bottom of [the _Cuore_ article](https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/Những_tấm_lòng_cao_cả). That’s supposed to mean either ‘full text’ or ‘source text’, both of which (according to Wiktionary) should be _ngang_ tone and thus unmarked _nguyên_. I don’t have a proper Vietnamese dictionary available, but Wiktionary and what else I’ve been able to find have no results at all for _nguyến_ in the _sác_ tone, so there’s a possibility that syllable doesn’t exist at all.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Indeed, Sino-Vietnamese ng-, being a sonorant, would generally be incompatible with _sắc_; sonorant + 去聲 would result in _nặng_.

Answer (score 1):

Vietnamese is notorious for having lots of near homonyms distinguished only by tone. This is the case with the very common family name Nguyễn versus the given name Nguyên. The latter was the middle name of the famous military leader Võ Nguyên Giáp.

Comment: This is true, but note that the question mentions the (potentially nonexistent) _Nguyến_ (_sác_ tone), not _Nguyên_ (_ngang_ tone). The fact that there is also a _ngang_ version of this syllable that happens to be used in (given) names certainly complicates matters, but it’s not strictly speaking what’s being asked about.